# Npm run watch runs just once in laravel with VUE & tailwinds

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

So I have a wierd issue with the watch cmd, when I run this cmd it will just run once, after that no errors and no changes. I'm using laravel 8 with VUE & tailwindcss.

package.json

```
    {
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.16",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "postcss": "^8.2.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.1.2",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.5",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "npm-watch": "^0.9.0",
        "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.1"
    }
}
```

webpack.mix.js

```
 mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()

    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ])
    .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, it was a typo. app.vue should have been App.vue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are requiring laravel-mix version 6+ in your package.json, however your npm scripts match those of previous version of laravel mix.
Take a look at this : https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/upgrade

Upgrade your npm scripts and it should work just fine.

Comment: Yes i see, made the changes but still the same, changes can be made just once, I do see the mix popup that it works but I dont see the changes made

Comment: Is the CLI refreshing in the terminal (with a message like 'recompiling assets..')

Comment: Ok so I guess you're not seeing the difference in the browser ? Maybe your browser is caching the asset ? Or it could be a different problem I am not aware of.
Did you try the npm run watch-poll command ?

Comment: I have tried watch-poll but that will give an error, unknow option --watch-poll. I have tried the refresh the browser cache but no changes. When I run npm run watch again it will change

Comment: @user759235 I would try to rm -rf the whole node_modules folder, and run npm install again to see if it do the trick

Comment: @user759235 Update the watch-poll script with this one (from the documentation) "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",

Comment: both things also no effect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232034/discussion-between-jascar-destin-and-user759235).

Comment: a chat would be nice but sadly i have to run(appointment)

Comment: small observation, running git bash works as it will keep watching(no changes on the front visible) and running terminal fro VS code will not keep watching the files(no updates made)

Answer (score 0):

I just spent several hours on the same problem (I am using Vue 3) before finding this thread, and it was coming from an upper/lowercase issue in the filename of the main component (`app.vue` instead of `App.vue`).

So if there is a capitalization inconsistency between the import of the file in `app.js` and the actual filename of any component, the behaviour is:

- The component is correctly included in `app.js` at initial build;
- It is correctly updated at first hot refresh;
- But then from second refresh, the `app.js` is not updated anymore so of course the browser keeps using its own cache.

If there is an obvious mistake in the filename (e.g. `pap.vue` instead of `app.vue`) then no problem : the initial build crashes with an explicit message (`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/App.vue'`) so the mistake is easy to be pointed out.

But with a simple lowercase/uppercase issue, whatever the position of the problem, then there is only this refresh issue with npm watch making it quite difficult to be pinpointed.
Also note that this issue occurs on MacOS and Linux, so as Windows implemented case sensitivity its own way it may be free from this issue (although I did not test it).

To avoid such issues, **always ensure the capitalization of your components is fully consistent between the import in `app.js` and the actual file name**.
If you need further information, [Vue Style Guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/style-guide/#component-name-casing-in-templates-strongly-recommended) lists the possible capitalizations for components' names.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.